# How to create a webservice from XSD and WSDL files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

Here's the problem:
I have a .WSDL file and a .XSD file and i need to create a web service to incorporate on the solution. 
The first thing i did was create a new project => WCF => WCF Service Application
After that I know I need some classes to create the web service arround it, so I tried different things to generate them from the WSDL and XSD files but it didn't work.

I've tried serveral ways:

1: `xsd /c myFile.xsd /n:mynamespace`

But has given me several errors:

`Schema validation warning: The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType.`

```xml
 <xsd:complexType name="R000000">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="EN">Cabeçalho</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="R00000100" type="datehourminsec">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>Data / Hora</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:length value="14"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="R00000110" type="version">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>Versão</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
```

2: `svcutil.exe /language:C# /out:myService.cs /n:*,mynamespace myFile.wsdl`

If i try to use this method also gives me plenty of errors,

```
Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='myurl.pt/myservice/service']/wsdl:portType[@name='ELServiceSoap']


Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='myurl.pt/myservice/service']/wsdl:portType[@name='ELServiceSoap']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='myurl.pt/myservice/service']/wsdl:binding[@name='ELServiceSoap']


Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='myurl.pt/myservice/service']/wsdl:binding[@name='ELServiceSoap']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='myurl.pt/myservice/service']/wsdl:service[@name='ELService']/wsdl:port[@name='ELServiceSoap']


Generating files...
Warning: No code was generated.
If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata documents did not contain any valid contracts or services
or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.

Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas make sure to use the /dataContractOnly option.
```

And even if i use the command with /dataContractOnly option, it reverts to the error that i had in the xsd command:

```
Error: An error occurred in the tool.

Error: The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType.
```

I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction in order to create the Web Service, but if I am, how can I solve this errors?